# Error: ENXIO: no such device or address, open '/dev/tty'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I installed node.js and npm

but I cannot get it fixed [Problem with my prompt-sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLv5Y.png)

[Running] node "/Users/edihan/repos/Hangman_AEK/Hangman_AEK.js"
node:internal/fs/utils:348
throw err;
^

Error: ENXIO: no such device or address, open '/dev/tty'
at Object.openSync (node:fs:595:3)
at prompt (/Users/edihan/repos/Hangman_AEK/node_modules/prompt-sync/index.js:67:10)
at Object. (/Users/edihan/repos/Hangman_AEK/Hangman_AEK.js:35:24)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1027:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
errno: -6,
syscall: 'open',
code: 'ENXIO',
path: '/dev/tty'
}

Node.js v18.10.0

Is anyone here to help?? :D

Comment: Please, avoid using screenshots, and prefer copy and paste of text content. Picture are not editable. And, furthermore, may be not available in the future. Your question and its answers are meant to be readable for the eternity, for all future people having the same problem :-)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It appears to be a [known bug](https://github.com/heapwolf/prompt-sync/issues/46) in some software which hasn't had an updated in three years and seems to have been abandoned.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a bug in third party code.